# Modify instance before it's saved on import

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm setting up an import process for a model which has a `ForeignKey` relationship, and I've got an extra field on the model where I'd like to store the provided value if it's an invalid ID of the related table. So if a `Passport` object doesn't exist for the UUID in the imported file, the value in the file gets added to the `invalid_passport` field. This way it can be viewed via django admin and potentially used after the import process is complete.

The ID's in question here are UUIDs, so there's a good chance that someone along the line will provide some invalid data.

```
class Result(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    passport = models.ForeignKey(
        to='results.Passport',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    invalid_passport = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_("An invalid passport number")
    )
```

The import file will contain a `passport` column for the UUID of the related object, but I'd like to save the provided value to `invalid_passport` if it doesn't match any `Passport` instances.

My resource looks like this;

```
class ResultResource(resources.ModelResource):
    """ Integrate django-import-export with the Result model """
    passport = fields.Field(
        column_name='passport',
        attribute='passport',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Passport, 'id')
    )

    class Meta:
        instance_loader_class = CachedInstanceLoader
        model = Result
        fields = (
            'id',
            'passport',
            'invalid_passport'
        )

    def init_instance(self, row=None):
        """ Initializes a new Django model. """
        instance = self._meta.model()
        if not instance.passport:
            instance.invalid_passport = row['passport']
        return instance

    def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        """ Sets the verified flags where there is a passport match. """
        if instance.passport:
            instance.verified = True
            instance.verified_by = self.import_job.author
            instance.invalid_passport = None
        else:
            pass
```

So when the instance is created, the value of the `Passport` ID is stored on `invalid_passport`. My theory being that in `before_save_instance` I can detect if the related `Passport` exists, except both sides of the `if` are being executed in `before_save_instance`.

Is this the wrong approach for this?

Comment: do you mean that invalid_passport field will store the passport if a passport has invalid_data such as if someone tried to add a passport that does not exist on the database? if I get it correct so, could you please tell me what is your question exactly?

Comment: Yeah, sorry that wasn't clear. If the UUID from the `passport` field in the CSV doesn't match a `Passport` object in the database, I'd like to keep a record of the value in the file using the `invalid_passport` field.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that if the passport doesn't exist, then `ForeignKeyWidget` will raise a `DoesNotExist` exception and your row will not be imported and will be marked as an error. However, this might be ok for you, because you might only be interested in recording the rows with no errors.

So unless I am missing something, I can't see how `before_save_instance()` would be called, because the `DoesNotExist` exception is raised first, which means none of the save logic is called.

If you look at [this line](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/33ce9ea7597440b20291b9ac5334526913e3172b/import_export/resources.py#L721) you can see that the exception is being added to an `Error` object, and then stored in the results for the import.  This seems to be a good option for recording the invalid passport ids.  In fact, the existing `Error` object would record the exception (`DoesNotExist`) and the row, so you would already have a record of the failing rows without any customisation.  You could override either the `Result` or the `Error` object to have more control over this.

Another idea might be to override `before_import()` to do some pre-processing.  In `before_import()`, you can maybe load all existing passport uuids into memory and then scan the dataset to remove any rows that don't exist.  This might not be practical if you have large tables.

However, you do say that you want to record the missing UUID on the model, so you could introduce a custom `ForeignKeyWidget` subclass which doesn't raise a `DoesNotExist` exception, and maybe raises a `ValidationError` instead.  In this case, the error will be stored in [`import_validation_errors`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/33ce9ea7597440b20291b9ac5334526913e3172b/import_export/resources.py#L696).  Then you could override `validate_instance()` to read the error back and store it on the model.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I was working on this backwards, starting with a successful import & thrown by the foreign key check showing both true & false. I think manipulating the dataset in `before_import` to move the value between columns for rows which don't hold a valid ID might work best.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I have a solution maybe it's not ordered perfectly but I will tell you what is the fit tool that helped me a lot in such these tasks. so, I think that **signals** is the best way to do achieve this task successfully

so, I will tell you the steps that I got in pseudo-code and you can modify them based on your idea:

- you will use pre_save to get the data that has been posted in the request
- into the function that you will apply the signals on it, open your CSV file
- take the UUID and search for it in a CSV file
- make a comparison between the data that comes from the CSV file and the UUID
- if data does not match any UUID or whatever your field that you want to compare with then, save that UUID in invalid_passport
- otherwise, don't save it and return your response as succeeded view

you can read more about pre_save and signals in here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/

**hint:**
the quickest way to open a file and get your data from the file will be using dataframe in pandas if you are familiar with pandas you will achieve this task quicker than using an open file in Django and also, will use strong performance in search because in pandas you won't need to use a loop to search for much data opposite to normal loop in python

Comment: Unfortunately signals wouldn't work in this instance because I'm using a bulk import so signals aren't fired. There are hooks in django-import-export to do this kind of thing. It's just a matter of figuring out the correct way to manipulate the data. And preferably before it saves it to avoid an impact on the database.